# MSChart Bar Chart not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bar-chart, mschart

I have the following code works fine:

```
string[] seriesArray = { "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5" };
double[] data = { 5, 10, 30, 60, 120 };

for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    Series series = chartTotalTime.Series.Add(seriesArray[i]);
    series.Points.Add(data[i]);
    chartTotalTime.Series[seriesArray[i]].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
    series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
}
```

When I change the code to `SeriesChartType.Bar` it breaks, just shows a white box with a red cross through it. Can someone tell me why? It seems odd considering it is pretty much the same chart rotated... I can find very few examples of how to implement this control.

Edited to add designer code:

```
        // 
        // chartTotalTime
        // 
        chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea1";
        this.chartTotalTime.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
        legend1.Name = "Legend1";
        this.chartTotalTime.Legends.Add(legend1);
        this.chartTotalTime.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 3);
        this.chartTotalTime.Name = "chartTotalTime";
        series1.ChartArea = "ChartArea1";
        series1.Legend = "Legend1";
        series1.Name = "Series1";
        this.chartTotalTime.Series.Add(series1);
        this.chartTotalTime.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(300, 300);
        this.chartTotalTime.TabIndex = 0;
        this.chartTotalTime.Text = "chart1";
```

Comment: could you put your `chararea` settings. It might be something to do with you `chartarea`. As such your code is working fine for me even when changed to `Bar`.

Comment: Added from the designer and didn't change anything from the default except the name of the control, please see original post for the designer code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got your problem. Remove the defalut series (series1) added by the chart control. This should fix your problem.

The default series is of type `SeriesCharType.Column`. You cannot mix series with different chart type. When all the series are of `Column` type then no issue in displaying. But when you change the type to `Bar` in the code, it is not compatible with the default series type.